# When do we need to define variables in loops?

Tags: python

Why is the line "total = 0" necessary in this code?

```
def sum_to(n):
    total = 0  # <<< this line
    for i in range(n):
        total= total + i
    return total
```

Also, I've noticed the same for "while" loops and was just wondering if that statement represents the starting number (which is 0), or just as a a way to introduce a foreign variable into an inbuilt function.

Thank you!

Comment: You are performing an operation on a variable that doesn't exist if you do not predefine `total=0` outside of your for loop.

Comment: Did you try that code *without* the `total = 0` line?

Comment: What do you expect `total= total + i` to do if `total` didn't already have a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It initialises the variable to a starting value before it is modified by the loop. Consider the alternative without it:

```
def sum_to(n):
    for i in range(n):
        total = total + i

    return total
```

On the first iteration of the loop it is asked to perform `total + i`, but it has never encountered `total` before and thus has no value it can possibly use for it.

If you ran that modified function you would get an error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

telling you that you are attempting to access a variable that has never been assigned a value. In this case Python can see that you are eventually going to give it a value, hence "before assignment". In a different context where this is not true the error might be

```
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

which means the variable is completely unknown.

Answer (score 1):

***Basic answer***

Python requires you to define the variable that you are going to use if you are doing operations on it.

For example

```
total+1

#error

NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

```
total = int()
total+1
#output
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the statement `total=0` represents the starting value of `total`.

If you don't initialize `total=0` or some other such statement, the computer won't know what the starting value of `total` should be.

In other words, without initializing `total=some_value_that_you_choose`, computer wouldn't "know" enough about the starting value of `total` to make sense of your code.